# okhttp 3 very slow

Tags: android, okhttp

I try to get json from a server, I use https on the server and every http request will go to the https version.

I get the data <s>and the data that I send works to</s> but it takes up to 45 sec to get a response back. The same code was faster with the build in http handler of android.

How can I speed up the request?

```
try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder().add("key", "2285");
        //formBuilder.add("phone", "000000");

        RequestBody formBody = formBuilder.build();
        Log.v("JsonRespons", reqUrl);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(reqUrl)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        okhttp3.Response response = null;

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException(response.message() + " " + response.toString());
        } else {
            output = response.body().string();
        }

        if(output != null) {
            Log.v("JsonRespons", output.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What Thread are you executing on? If you don't know much about threads just go for the async as its done in the following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967505/android-okhttp-asynchronous-calls

Comment: @toshkinl - i have build a class for getting json from a url, this part of the code is from that class

Answer (score 0):

You must consider some important things :

- Executing `Okhttp3` request away from `UI thread`, like `AsyncTask`.
- **Don't** forget to close response body after complete.

  ```
      new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>(){

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
          String strResponse = null;
          try {
              Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
              if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                  strResponse = response.body().string();
                  response.close();  // DON't forget to close body =@response.body().close();
              }

          }catch (Exception ex){
          }
          return strResponse;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
          // Update UI here
      }
  };
  ```
- Using `okhttp3` thread using `enqueue`

  ```
  client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
          // When failure 
          mActivity.runOnUiThread(); // If need to update UI
      }

      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
          if (response.isSuccessful()){
              String result = response.body().string();
              mActivity.runOnUiThread(); // update UI under UI thread.
              response.close();  // close response body.
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Creating `OkHttp3Client` and configure timeout.

  ```
  private static OkHttpClient createHttpclient() {
  final OkHttpClient.Builder builder =  new OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  setSocketFactory(builder); // To handle SSL certificate. 
  return builder.build();
  }
  ```