# Why is okhttp3 on android slower doing requests than a desktop computer?

Tags: android, https, okhttp

I started caveman profiling network request code and found out that some APIs that should be about 3s took around 8s instead. After scattering a lot of `println()` around I reached to the point where between:

```
mOkHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(okcallback);
```

and

```
public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) {
    System.out.println("GGGN in 1");
```

7 seconds elapsed in between, suggesting okhttp3 is the culprit. After reading some other answers I stumbled upon the [Events wiki page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Events) which contains an `EventListener` example to debug events in the http pipeline. Here is the output:

```
18:36:54.389 GGGH 0007 https://someurl/
18:36:54.390 GGGH 0007 0,000 callStart
18:36:54.390 GGGN 5
18:36:54.392 GGGH 0007 0,002 connectionAcquired
18:36:54.392 GGGH 0007 0,002 requestHeadersStart
18:36:54.392 GGGH 0007 0,003 requestHeadersEnd
18:36:54.392 GGGH 0007 0,003 requestBodyStart
18:36:54.393 GGGH 0007 0,003 requestBodyEnd
18:36:54.393 GGGH 0007 0,003 responseHeadersStart
18:37:01.680 GGGH 0007 7,291 responseHeadersEnd
18:37:01.681 GGGH 0007 7,291 responseBodyStart
18:37:01.682 GGGN in 1
18:37:01.682 GGGN in 2
18:37:01.683 GGGN in 3
18:37:01.683 GGGQuery 2
18:37:01.688 GGGQuery 3
18:37:01.689 GGGN in 4
18:37:01.689 GGG callback 4
18:37:01.690 GGG callback 5
18:37:01.715 GGG callback 6
18:37:01.715 GGGH 0007 7,325 responseBodyEnd
18:37:01.715 GGGH 0007 7,326 connectionReleased
18:37:01.715 GGGH 0007 7,326 callEnd
```

It seems that the client spends around 7s between `responseHeadersStart` and `responseHeadersEnd`. However, when I run the same query from a mac on the same network, I get 2.03s for the request.

Why is the difference so big, and can I do something to make the mobile go faster? I tried the suggestions from [other questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288610/okhttp-3-very-slow), but I'm already doing all mentioned there.

I was trying this on a low end Xiaomi Redmi3S, but then I repeated the tests on a Xiaomi Mi6, a faster device, and ironically the test there runs 1s slower! Mobile APK is compiled in release mode with proguard, so I build, run, then fetch logs with grep to avoid adding any slowdown to the devices. OkHttp3 version is 3.12.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the headers. The requests being done on the computer were slightly different than the ones on the client. Replicating all the header fields provides the same performance on both pc and mobile.